# Css/JS issues with N2CMS 2.5.9 and Dinamico templates

Tags: n2cms, dinamico

I sometimes have problems loading java script and CSS, and i think that Url.ThemedContent is the culprit.

Everything will work perfect, but if I refresh my page multiple times fast (CTRL + R in chrome) to clear my js-cache, for some reason it just crashes my file loading.

It says that /N2/Resources/..... cant be found, and it messes the page up completely, only way to fix it is to change the web.config so that the page recycles.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the N2.Management.NoZip package. If that doesn't work, it sounds like a bug, so file an issue at http://github.com/n2cms/n2cms so that the developers will fix it.